# Google App Engine NDB Query on Many Locations

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, google-app-engine

I am developing a web app based on the Google App Engine. 
It has some hundreds of places (name, latitude, longitude) stored in the Data Store. 
My aim is to show them on google map. 
Since they are many I have registered a javascript function to the idle event of the map and, when executed, it posts the map boundaries (minLat,maxLat,minLng,maxLng) to a request handler which should retrieve from the data store only the places in the specified boundaries.

The problem is that it doesn't allow me to execute more than one inequality in the query (i.e. Place.latminLat, Place.lntminLng).

How should I do that? (trying also to minimize the number of required queries)

Comment: have a look at geopoints, but it's in the search API and relatively costly. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Comment: Can you post your code and the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide the map into regions, make an algorithm to translate the current position into a region, and then get the places by an equality query. In this case you would need overlapping regions, allow places to be part of many of them, and ideally make regions bigger than the size of the map, in order to minimize the need for multiple queries.

That was just an outline of the idea, an actual implementation would be a little bit more complicated, but I don't have one at hand.

Another option is using geohashes, which are actually pretty cool, you can read a write up about them, along with code samples, here: [Scalable, fast, accurate geo apps using Google App Engine + geohash + faultline correction](http://hitching.net/2009/11/10/scalable-fast-accurate-geo-apps-using-google-app-engine-geohash-faultline-correction/)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how frequently the data points are updated, but assuming 1) they're updated infrequently and 2) there are only hundreds of points, then consider just querying them all once, and storing them sorted in memcache.  Then your handler function would just fetch from memcache and filter in memory.

This wouldn't scale indefinitely but it would likely be cheaper than querying the Datastore every time, due to the way App Engine pricing works.